# Using numba jitclass with some methods in pure python?

Tags: python, numba

Is there a way to keep the python implementation for some methods of a jitclass ?

My class indeed have a few methods which have no need of compiling, and which use some external lib incompatible with numba. One solution could be to remove those methods from the class to 'numbify';  but this requires a refactoring of a larger code base I would prefer to avoid.

Here is some simplified example:

```
from numba import typeof
from numba.experimental import jitclass
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

@jitclass([('_some_attribute', typeof(1))])
class MyClass:
    _some_attribute: int

    def __init__(self, some_attribute):
        self._some_attribute = some_attribute

    def do_stuff_fast(self, x: np.array):
        # Used in the inner loop of mycode. Must be fast, numba is welcomed here.
        return x[self._some_attribute]

    # @numba.please_do_not_jit_this!!
    def do_stuff_slow(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        # This code does not need to get compiled. It is in the same class to keep things well encapsulated.
        # (and keeping it here avoids to break my API. )
        return df["toto"].values[self._some_attribute]

instance = MyClass(5)
print(instance.do_stuff_fast(np.ones(10)) )
df = pd.DataFrame( {'toto' :np.zeros(10) } )
print( instance.do_stuff_slow(df) ) #TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)   non-precise type pyobject
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution?